# "no such column" error when running a data migration with django-south

Tags: django, data-migration, django-south

I've imported some metrics events into a Django project. Next, I grouped the Events into Sessions, defined as a series of contiguous events within a given time window.

My models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, db_index=True)
    id1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, db_index=True)
    id2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='events', null=True, db_index=True)
    session = models.ForeignKey('Session', related_name='events', null=True, db_index=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '"%s" event' % self.name or 'unnamed'

class Session(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sessions', null=True)
```

I'm now trying to denormalize the start and end times of these sessions to avoid having to do MAX and MIN aggregations on all the sessions' events. So my new Session model looks like this.

```
class Session(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sessions', null=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, null=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, null=True)
```

I've added the fields, created a schema migration (which runs fine) and have created a data migration:

```
import datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import DataMigration
from django.db import models

class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        "Write your forwards methods here."
        orm.Session.objects  \
            .annotate(
                start_time=models.Min('events__time'),
                end_time=models.Max('events__time'))  \
            .update(start=models.F('start_time'), end=models.F('end_time'))

    def backwards(self, orm):
        "Write your backwards methods here."
        pass


    models = {
        'auth.group': {
```

...

```
    'metrics_import.event': {
        'Meta': {'object_name': 'Event'},
        'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
        'id1': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'db_index': 'True', 'max_length': '255', 'blank': 'True'}),
        'id2': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '255', 'blank': 'True'}),
        'name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'db_index': 'True', 'max_length': '255', 'blank': 'True'}),
        'session': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'related_name': "'events'", 'null': 'True', 'to': "orm['metrics_import.Session']"}),
        'time': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'db_index': 'True'}),
        'user': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'related_name': "'events'", 'null': 'True', 'to': "orm['auth.User']"})
    },
    'metrics_import.session': {
        'Meta': {'object_name': 'Session'},
        'end': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'null': 'True', 'db_index': 'True'}),
        'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
        'start': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'null': 'True', 'db_index': 'True'}),
        'user': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'related_name': "'sessions'", 'null': 'True', 'to': "orm['auth.User']"})
    }
}
```

Seems simple enough, but running the data migration gives:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such column: metrics_import_event.time
```

I've checked that the column does, in fact, exist, both from the django shell:

```
>>> Event.objects.all()[0].time
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 19, 3, 0, 3)
```

and directly in the DB schema:

```
sqlite> .schema metrics_import_event
CREATE TABLE "metrics_import_event" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "id1" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "id2" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "time" datetime NOT NULL,
    "user_id" integer REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"),
    "session_id" integer
);
CREATE INDEX "metrics_import_event_3a04cc98" ON "metrics_import_event" ("time");
CREATE INDEX "metrics_import_event_52094d6e" ON "metrics_import_event" ("name");
CREATE INDEX "metrics_import_event_6b4dc4c3" ON "metrics_import_event" ("session_id");
CREATE INDEX "metrics_import_event_fbfc09f1" ON "metrics_import_event" ("user_id");
```

I'm sure there's something silly that I'm missing, but can't figure out what.

Thanks!

Edit: Note that the initial schema migration was applied with  `--fake`, in case that matters somehow.

Comment: You said you ran the --fake migration previously -- the samples you listed are from before running the final migration?

Comment: @Alvin yes, I ran the initial migration with --fake because I already had created the initial tables with syncdb. The SQL output I showed is before the migration is run (it can't run, because it fails -- hence the question :)

Comment: Have you tried running a profiler to see what the query being generated is? Curious if the time column is being wrapped in `time` to avoid hitting a reserved word?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are trying to run an update statement with a join -- I'm pretty sure this is not supported by Sqlite; that is, it could probably be implemented using a 'with' clause, but I doubt Django does this (since with-clauses were only added to SQLite at version 3.8.3, released long after Django 1.6). I think you're getting something very close to this:

```
$ sqlite3 
SQLite version 3.8.3.1 2014-02-11 14:52:19
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table x (a int, b int);
sqlite> insert into x values(1,2);
sqlite> select * from x;
1|2
sqlite> create table y (c int, d int);
sqlite> update x set b = min (y.d);
Error: no such column: y.d
```

I think you can set logging up to print all SQL before it's executed, this way you can get more info.

(this answer guesses that, actually, this has nothing to do with South -- the problem is in Django).